# Rename multiple tables at once

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am needing some sql code that I can use regularly to rename multiple tables at once.  The code below is what I would want if I could use the update statement but cannot.  Simple as possible.

```
UPDATE sys.tables 
SET name = SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX('PP_', name),LEN(name))
WHERE CHARINDEX('PP_', name) > 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sp_rename` to rename objects. Below is an example that generates and executes the needed script.

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) =
    (SELECT 'EXEC sp_rename ''' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ''', ''' + SUBSTRING(t.name, CHARINDEX('PP_', t.name),LEN(t.name)) + ''';'
    FROM sys.tables AS t
    JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    WHERE CHARINDEX('PP_', t.name) > 0
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)');

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

To answer the additional question asked in the comments, you can generate a single DROP TABLE statement for these tables using the script below. Note that this method might not work if the tables have foreign key relationships since it doesn't drop in dependency order.

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) =
    N'DROP TABLE ' + STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name)
    FROM sys.tables AS t
    JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    --WHERE CHARINDEX('PP_', t.name) > 0
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,'')
    + N';';
```

Comment: That helped me perfectly thank you.  Is there something similar to delete the same tables that meet that same criteria?

Comment: Do you mean `DROP TABLE`? Just change the SELECT list to `SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ';'`

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to drop them all at once?

Comment: @BenW, I updated my answer to address your question.